# Explanation of SQL: BEGIN, COMMIT flow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I try to understand, how that SQL command works:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE post SET hits = hits + 1;
-- run from another session:  DELETE FROM post WHERE hits = 10;
COMMIT;
```

Let's say, we hahe a rows with hits = 9 and 10.
Then we run that query, and then what? What (and why) will our rows look like?

Comment: Why don't you simply test? I mean - it takes 10 seconds to start 2 terminals, and test. And you'll get valuable information in a way that will teach you more.

Comment: But how to test it in that very small ammount of time, when transaction is being active (between BEGIN and COMMIT)?

Comment: Start transaction, issue update. then, in other psql, run the delete.

Comment: Just don't send the `commit` in the first session.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on transaction isolation level in each session but by default
all changes made by UPDATE will be visible to other session only after executing COMMIT. 
So your DELETE session will behave like there was no UPDATE at all.

Comment: There is no isolation level in Postgres that will ever make non-committed data visible to other transactions.

Comment: So if I understand well - BEGIN - COMMIT puts a lock on affected rows, and until COMMIT that rows some kind of invisible for other queries?

Comment: @VitaliyG: you should read the manual carefully: "*When you select the level Read Uncommitted you **really get Read Committed***" (emphasis mine) - there is **no** way to run un-committed day in Postgres

Comment: Yes it is not implemented for now

Comment: It will never be implemented. `read uncommitted` is simply a hack by other DBMS to allow for non-blocking concurrent reads and writes

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go so far as to say that it will be never implemented. It's just that currently there are no plans on it, and no work is being done (afaik). There are some hacks to achieve it, though - http://www.depesz.com/2012/04/04/lets-talk-dirty/